# Why is my Drupal 8 module show Page not found?

Tags: symfony, drupal, yaml, drupal-8

I'm following the [Modules, Routes and Controllers](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/drupal8-under-the-hood/modules-routes-controllers#play) tutorial. However, I kept getting "Page not found" regardless of "Clear all cache".

dino_roar.info.yml file:

```
name: Dino ROAR
type: module
description: "ROAR at you"
package: Custom
core: 8.x
```

dino_roar.routing.yml

```
dino_says:
  path: /the/dino/says/
  defaults:
    _controller: Drupal\dino_roar\Controller\RoarController::roar
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

and src/Controller/RoarController.php file:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\dino_roar\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class RoarController
{
    public function roar(){
        return new Response('ROOOOAR');
    }
}
```

When accessing through: http://drupal-8.dd:8083/the/dino/says/ I get the page not found error. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Below is my folder structure:
[image]

And this is what it looks when I collapsed the src folder.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some help from Shashwat Purav at Drupal.org. Below is the routing file I've changed to that works.

```
dino_roar.dino_says:
    path: /dino/says
    defaults:
        _controller: '\Drupal\dino_roar\Controller\RoarController::roar'
    requirements:
        _permission: 'access content'
```

Comment: It looks like I need to add the backward slash before the "Drupal" in my controller. What is odd is that I have another "hello world" test module that I do not put the backward slash before the word Drupal and it works on that one.

Answer (score 0):

The main module info yml file has to be named after the following scheme:

```
module_name.info.yml
```

So it's dino_roar.info.yml for your module. Also you need to enable your module, but as far as I know when the correct named info yml file is not present Drupal doesn't even know about your module.

Also make sure your folder structure is correct:

```
dino_roar
  --> src
    --> Controller
           RoarController.php
  dino_roar.info.yml
  dino_roar.routing.yml
```

Comment: I just make the changes, clear all cache, and it's still not working. Is enable my module mean installing it? If so, yes, I did install the module. Drupal 8 was able to see the module.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything wrong.. have you double checked your module folder structure?

Comment: I just added my module folder structure to my original post. I don't see any abnormality.

Comment: Your .yml files are in the wrong directory! They are in /src but should be a level above.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that but it's not. The .yml files are outside of the src folder. I just uploaded another pic with the src folder collapsed.

Comment: Hm, then I don't know, maybe try and disable and enable the module and clear cache. Everything else looks right..

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of your original routing issue,
 you should change "path: /the/dino/says/"  to "path: /the/dino/says"

after remove the last slash,  should be fine .

Comment: I tried removing the slash after the "says" but that wasn't it.

Comment: did you clean the cache ?  after you change anything in .yml file, you better clean your cache first . i did my test on my computer, once i removed that slash, it functions correctly, otherwise i will have the same issue as you before